# Equivalent of C/C++ setlocale(LC_ALL, "C") in Java?

Tags: java, locale

I want to compare String with "C" locale in Java, however there is no predefined "C" locale in Locale.class. Which one should I use? Locale.ROOT?

Comment: Yes, `Locale.ROOT` would be the closet match, being the "neutral" locale, which is what the "C" locale is too.